# Python: Parsing XML autoadd all key/value pairs

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I searched a long and have tried a lot! but I can't get my mind open for this totally easy scenario. I need to say that I'm a python newbie but a very good bash coder ;o) I have written some code with python but maybe there is a lot I need to learn yet so do not be too harsh to me ;o) I'm willing to learn and I read python docs and many examples and tried  a lot on my own but now I'm at a point where I picking in the dark..

I parse content provided as XML. It is about 20-50 MB big.
My XML Example:

```
<MAIN>
  <NOSUBEL>abcd</NOSUBEL>
  <NOSUBEL2>adasdasa</NOSUBEL2>
  <MULTISUB>
    <WHATEVER>
      <ANOTHERSUBEL>
        <ANOTHERONE>
          (how many levels can not be said / can change)
        </ANOTHERONE>
      </ANOTHERSUBEL>
     </WHATEVER>
   </MULTISUB>..
   <SUBEL2>
     <FOO>abcdefg</FOO>
   </SUBEL2>
   <NOSUBEL3>abc</NOSUBEL3>
   ... 
   and so on 
</MAIN>
```

This is the main part of parsing it (if you need more details pls ask):

```
from lxml import etree
resp = my.request(some call args)
xml = etree.XML(resp)

for element in xml.findall(".//MAIN"):

   # this works fine but is not generic enough:   
   my_dict = OrderedDict()
   for only1sub in element.iter(tag="SUBEL2"):
        for i in only1sub:
            my_dict[i.tag] = i.text
```

This just working fine with 1 subelement but that means I need to know which one in the tree has subelements and which not. This could change in the future or be added. 
Another problem is MULTISUB. With the above code I'm able to parse until the first tag only.

**The goal**

What I *WANT* to achieve is - at best:

A) Having one function / code snippet which is able to parse the whole XML content and if there is a subelement (e.g. with "if len(x)" or whatever) then parse to the next level until you reach a level without a subelement/tree. Then go on to B)

B) For each XML tag found which has NO subelements I want to update the dictionary with the tag name and the tag text.

C) I want to do that for all available elements - the tag  and the direct child tag names (e.g. "NOSUBEL2" or "MULTISUB") will **not** change (often) so it will be ok to use them as a start point for parsing.

What I tried so far was to chain several loops like for and while and for again and so on but nothing was full successful. I also dived my hands into python generators because I thought I can do something with the next() function but also nothing. But again I may have not the knowledge to use them correctly and so I'm happy for every answer..

At the end the thing I need is so easy I believe. I only want to have key value pairs from the tag name and the tag content that couldn't be so hard? Any help greatly appreciated..

Can you help me reaching the goal?

(Already a thanks for reading until here!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) - a technique of running some procedure *inside* that procedure, but for sub-problem of the original problem. In this case: either, for each subelement of some element run this procedure (in case there are subelements) or update your dictionary with element's tag name and text.

I assume at the end you're interested in having dictionary ([`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)) containing "flat representation" of whole element tree's leaves' (nodes without subelements) tag names/text values, which in your case, printed out, would look like this:

```
OrderedDict([('NOSUBEL', 'abcd'), ('NOSUBEL2', 'adasdasa'), ('ANOTHERONE', '(how many levels can not be said / can change)'), ('FOO', 'abcdefg'), ('NOSUBEL3', 'abc')])
```

Generally, you would define a function that will either call itself with part of your data (in this case: subelements, if there are any) or do something (in this case: update some instance of dictionary).

Since I don't know the details behind `my.request` call, I've replaced that by parsing from string containing valid XML, based on the one you provided. Just replace constructing the `tree` object.

```
resp = """<MAIN>
    <NOSUBEL>abcd</NOSUBEL>
    <NOSUBEL2>adasdasa</NOSUBEL2>
    <MULTISUB>
        <WHATEVER>
            <ANOTHERSUBEL>
                <ANOTHERONE>(how many levels can not be said / can change)</ANOTHERONE>
            </ANOTHERSUBEL>
        </WHATEVER>
    </MULTISUB>
    <SUBEL2>
        <FOO>abcdefg</FOO>
    </SUBEL2>
    <NOSUBEL3>abc</NOSUBEL3>
</MAIN>"""


from collections import OrderedDict
from lxml import etree


def update_dict(element, my_dict):
    # lxml defines "length" of the element as number of its children.
    if len(element):  # If "length" is other than 0.
        for subelement in element:
            # That's where the recursion happens. We're calling the same
            # function for a subelement of the element.
            update_dict(subelement, my_dict)

    else:  # Otherwise, subtree is a leaf.
        my_dict[element.tag] = element.text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Change/amend it with your my.request call.
    tree = etree.XML(resp)  # That's a <MAIN> element, too.

    my_dict = OrderedDict()
    # That's the first invocation of the procedure. We're passing entire
    # tree and instance of dictionary.
    update_dict(tree, my_dict)

    print(my_dict)  # Just to see that dictionarty was filled with values.
```

As you can see, I didn't use any tag name in the code (except for the XML source, of course).

I've also added missing import from `collections`.

Comment: oh... that looks absolutely great and you have explained it very good! Higly appreciated really! I can not await to test that within my code but I need to wait until my vacation has ended :) Nevertheless I will mark it as answered because it looks like exactly for what I'm looking for. Many thx again!